# How do I debug my Xamarin app in Android when it's started via an intent?

Tags: debugging, xamarin, xamarin.android

My app works well when it's started normally. However when it's started with an intent it crashes.
Is there a way to use the debugger when I have to start the app via the intent?

Comment: 1) You can review the `logcat` output for the crash details. 2) You can start a debugging session with the app, hit the home button, (assumably) launch the other app, perform your "share" (or other function) that sends the intent to your app... (or use `adb` to simulate sending the intent) and your app will be active again and debugging (so add breakpoints before hitting the home button if needed).

Comment: @SushiHangover : Unfortunately, the bug doesn't appear if I minimze the app but only on app start via intent. Is there a way to get the logcat without rooting (or having the debugging session)?

Comment: You don't need root to use logcat. You can access it through Visual Studio using the Device Log pad/view. Otherwise run `adb logcat` in your command line if you have `adb` in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: @Christian What Cheesebaron said.... Android `logcat` output is always available on the device|emulator. https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat